Blazor Snowpack: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"
I'm trying to use npm and snowpack in Blazor following this article
https://nbarraud.github.io/js-in-blazor.html
But when trying to import the bundle i get this error:
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at BlazorApp2.Components.Pages.Home.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\Components\Pages\Home.razor:line 10
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Smaller issue that can be solved by lowering the snowpack version to 3.0.13 for example is this one:
[@snowpack/plugin-optimize] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\wwwroot\js\_snowpack\optimize-manifest.json'
1>C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2.csproj(10,3): error MSB3073: The command "cd JS && npm run snowpack-build" exited with code 1.

Anyway you can find the repo here:
https://github.com/MefestoSerlo/blazor-snowpack-issue/tree/master

Did you make sure to run all npm commands listed in your linked article? The full set of steps you took to reproduce this would go a long way towards figuring out the issue.

Snowpack requires relative paths when importing local modules. For example, if you're importing lodash, ensure that you're importing it via a relative path or using a correct alias if configured.
like this
import _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';
instead of
import _ from 'lodash'; import o from "lodash";

I tried that, still Blazor fails to import module.
